# Chrome: Potential onmousemove Bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I ran into an issue that may be a bug in Chrome, but I was hoping some more seasoned developers could take a look at the problem.  I'm using the dom-drag JavaScript library by youngpup (https://github.com/aboodman/dom-drag/blob/gh-pages/dom-drag.js) and noticed that it's not functioning correctly in Chrome.  The error is occurring on line 86.

For some reason Chrome is registering a document.onmousemove event even if the mouse has not been moved. I've tried it on every other browser and Chrome is the only one causing the the event to be triggered when a user single clicks.  Would this be considered a bug and if so, could anyone recommend a workaround to resolve the issue?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170631

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Looks like this is going to cause me quite a few headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I was using drag.js, and I faced the same problem. I can see that from the link that PlantTheldea gave 2 years ago, chrome didn't fixed it.
In my side, I had draggable items in my DOM that should accept the click event handler. But **onmousemove event was triggered during click event** if the mouse was not moving. This bug was happening with Chrome.

So I suppose that other people may face the same issue. Here is how I solved it with drag.js:

1 - Go to your onmousemove handler

2 - Check if there are movement in X or Y. If there is any movement then you return true.

Example with the handler of drag.js that I edited:

```
// onmousemove handler for the document level
// activated after left mouse button is pressed on draggable element
handler_onmousemove = function (e) {
        if(e.movementX === 0 && e.movementY == 0){
            // No movement detected
            return true; // We can continue with other handlers as click
        }
```

Hope it can help.